# Program gives strange "BadValue" error message with no error line-number, and debugger doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx

When I try to run my program, Eclipse gives me this error in completely red text.

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I have tried commenting out various statements and using Eclipse's debugger. The program still gives the same error immediately, no matter where I put the debugger's breakpoints.

What might be causing this, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

I haven't included any of my code because my program is too large and I can't narrow the problem down. Also, the fact that the debugger's not working makes me think this has more to do with how Eclipse is handling my program anyway.

I am using Oracle's Java-8 with JavaFX and Eclipse 2018-19 (4.9.0) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: How are you running your program? On what environment? What kind of OpenGL drivers do you have installed? Because that error indicates an issue with [GLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am running my program just by clicking the "run" button in Eclipse. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, the program worked on it before. As far as I know I have no OpenGL drivers installed. I am not programming with OpenGL. I don't know what GLX is. If it matters, my graphics driver is listed as nvidia-driver-410.

Comment: Open**GL** Extension to the **X** Window System. I did give you a link.

Comment: Yes, I've read it. I'm just letting you know it's a bit beyond me. I don't really understand what it's talking about.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to help further I should think; you have posted no code. And even if you did post the code, I don't think you have a MCVE (the issue is related to your local environment, and your OpenGL configuration). Backup your software, reinstall your OS and see if the issue persists. Before going to that extreme, it might be worth testing your software on a different computer. If it fails there too then you're going to want to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you anyway. I'll start trying different things.